# Create table using definition variable

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a table in PostgreSQL using python psycopg2.
So when I execute: create_table(location) it makes the location table.
I've looked at various tutorials around the web. but I just can't get it to work, any ideas?

```
import psycopg2

def create_table(table_name):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db host=localhost user=user password=pw")
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the database") 

    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE public.s% (
                id serial NOT NULL,
                x double precision,
                y double precision,
                z double precision,
                geom geometry, 
                dist double precision,
                CONSTRAINT test21_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))
                ''')
    except:
        print("Error!")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    cur.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `s%` in your original code looks like an attempt at [%-formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), though the conversion specifier should be `%s` and you do not actually format the string. Since you are using `psycopg2` you should use the [SQL string composition](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) tools offered by it:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

stmt = sql.SQL('''CREATE TABLE public.{} (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    x double precision,
    y double precision,
    z double precision,
    geom geometry, 
    dist double precision,
    CONSTRAINT test21_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))
    ''')

cur.execute(stmt.format(sql.Identifier(table_name)))
```

Note that `stmt.format()` is not `str.format()`, but [`SQL.format()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL.format). This handles quoting the identifier correctly, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
try:
        cur.execute('
        CREATE TABLE public.{} (
                id serial NOT NULL,
                x double precision,
                y double precision,
                z double precision,
                geom geometry, 
                dist double precision,
                CONSTRAINT test21_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))
                '.format(table_name))
```